# set the height of freetextbox

Tags: asp.net, freetextbox

How should I go about setting the height of freetextbox? I want to size the textbox reasonably based on the lenght of the text in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

simply set the height property of  textbox as much you want... like..

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server" Width="590px" Height="300px" ></FTB:FreeTextBox>
```